# What's wrong with my garlic? Overwatered or lacked nutrients?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, containers, garlic

I'm growing 9 garlics in one container. Previously 10 but the other one died. Currently, some of their leaves are turning yellow and they are still one month old. I used a soil-less medium and I apply organic liquid fertilizer every 2 weeks. I also water them when I think (I'm not really sure) the soil is dry.

What could be the cause of the yellowing leaves? I'm not sure if it's because they lack nutrients or I'm overwatering them.

I'm from the Philippines by the way.

[image: garlic leaves turning yellow]

Comment: That is a very odd looking soil less medium.  Can you describe what is in it?

Comment: @kevinsky According to the packaging, it's "made from a mixture of high-quality, all-organic composted materials, slow-release fertilizers, and essential materials." I just bought it in a hardware store. I'm a newbie by the way when it comes to gardening.

Comment: What's the brand name and product name of the medium?

Comment: @charliecat Under watering is my guess. I don't like this soil-less compound your using. Is there a reason in particular your using it?

Comment: Are they in full sun? You might try shading them some. I know our garlic seems to prefer partial shade, and yellows in strong sun (perhaps especially in the afternoon/evening sun).

Comment: @greggles Ramgo Potting Mix

Comment: @Rob I don't have soil here in my home so I just considered buying potting mixes. And it was the only one available in the hardware store.

Comment: @Shule I placed it somewhere it's supposed to get full sun, but it's been raining a lot lately. Light to heavy rain. I live in a tropical country and it's rainy season now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my garlic plants are neither overwatered nor did they lack nutrients. They have [onion maggots](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delia_antiqua).

I pulled out the yellowed ones and saw that their roots were rotten and there were white wriggly things moving about.

[image: roots with maggots]

Answer (score 2):

Garlic is an odd crop. It grows well in Ontario but not exactly where I live; the soil is too sandy and "hot". Garlic likes cool, verging on cold conditions. Here we plant going into the fall, the garlic makes roots and may begin to emerge, the soil then freezes hard for months on end, and then in spring the garlic bulbs wake and continue to grow until the weather really warms up at which point the garlic goes dormant.

The heat of your tropical location (this little detail would do well added to your question) will be a problem for garlic which needs cold. Your best bet is to experiment with varieties, keep an eye open for people locally who have success and ask them for a bulb and tips on what can be done to get the garlic to grow. [This site](https://www.mmmgarlic.com/growing-garlic-3/growing-garlic-warm-climates/) has some comments on suitable varieties.

Soil moisture has to be constant but not flooded; here heavy mulching is practiced but in your case the mulching might be unnecessary and even harmful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I edited the description and added where I'm located.